# How much current various kind of body tissues can tolerate without any serious damage?

Tags: electrical-stimulation

Human body can tolerate some amount of current. How much current (and duration) various kind of body tissues can tolerate without any serious damage?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! What research have you done before asking it here?

Comment: @another 'Homo sapien' I hope you're not asking him to electrocute someone are you?

Comment: @PrittBalagopal haha of course I don't mean a practical ;)

Comment: Regarding this, if the O.P has access to organs from a hospital or any source (preferably a rejected one for grafts), the O.P could do an experiment to find out. I invite @wgc to answer his own question after doing some research. It would be great for us to learn new stuff (not for electrocuting people of course).